# Hessian Related convex optimization question

Tags: convex-optimization

My precise question is from an exercise;

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 → \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function. Prove that there exists a $λ ∈ R$ such that $g : \mathbb{R}^2 → \mathbb{R}$ defined as $g(x) := f (x) + (λ/2)||x||^2$ is convex.

**Hint: compute the Hessian of $g$ and prove that for $λ$ large enough, this Hessian is positive definite.**

I am trying to follow the hint but immediately running into errors when computing the hessian of g.

I am really not sure how to proceed given the $f(x)$ along with $||x||$. I mean we only still have the one variable $x$, so what possibility is there for double derivatives?

$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     g_{ff} & g_{fx} \\
     g_{fx} & g_{xx}
  \end{array} \right]
$$

Which seems rather silly. Would anyone care point out my misinterpration/fundamentally flaw, and lead me on the right track?

Comment: The functions $f$ and $g$ are defined as functions that take a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as input and return a single real number as output. So the $x$ is actually a vector containing two numbers. You can compute derivatives with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: I have edited my answer after a good remark from @SZhu. Actually, the second derivatives must be bounded to find a fixed $\lambda$.

Comment: That is right. As stated, the theorem is *false*.

Answer (score 2):

By considering $\| \cdot\|$ the $2$-norm, the Hessian is given by

\begin{equation}
H =  \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1^2} + \lambda & \frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} \\
 \frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1}& \frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2^2} + \lambda\\
\end{array} \right],
\end{equation}  for $x = (x_1,x_2)$.

The matrix $H$ is positive definite if and only if all principal minors are positive. Thus,

$$ \frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1^2} + \lambda > 0,$$ and

$$\left(  \frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1^2} + \lambda \right)\left(  \frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2^2} + \lambda \right) - \left(\frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} \right)\left(\frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1} \right) >0.$$

You have to assume other constraints for $f(x)$. Notice that you should have $$ \frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1^2} > -\infty,$$ for all $x_1$ and $x_2$, otherwise there is no $\lambda$ that guarantees  the convexity of $g(x)$. I take the example given by @SZhu as follows.

If $\frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1^2}=-e^{x_1+x_2}$, then there is no fixed $\lambda$ such that the first principal minor is positive for all $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Yet, you also should have

$$ \frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2^2} > -\infty$$ and

$$\left(\frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} \right)\left(\frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1} \right) < \infty,$$ for all $x_1$ and $x_2$.

If these conditions are satisfied then for $\lambda$ large enough, it is easy to see that the two principal minors are positive.

Comment: The only constraint on $f$ is twice differentiable, right? Consider $f(x) = -e^{x_1+x_2}$, which is good I think. However, $\frac{\partial^2 f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1^2}=-e^{x_1+x_2}$ can tend to $-\infty$. So no fixed $\lambda$ can work for this function. Correct me if make errors here.

Comment: Well, suppose you say a finite $\lambda$ work, but I can also find finite $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $H$ is not positive definite thereby $g(x)$ is not strongly convex. This is basically from the definition of convergence to $\infty$.

Comment: Well, then your $\lambda$ is not fixed.

Comment: Ok, let me ask this. Do you want a fixed $\lambda$ that work for all $x$ or for a given $x$ you can find a $\lambda$ that make $g$ has positive definite hessian?

Comment: I was directed here by @Michael Grant. You may also like to see my problem that is kind of related to this one. [click here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106154/any-example-of-strongly-convex-functions-whose-gradients-are-lipschitz-continuou) Thanks.

Comment: @SZhu, You are right in the sense that more information is missing about $f(x)$. I understand you now. Sorry!

Comment: @SZhu, I've edited the answer. Thanks for the remarks! :)

Comment: I agree with SZhu. I don't think this proof is complete for the example he offers, and in fact I think the theorem is incorrect, and his example proves it.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, yes, I know! But I have imposed other constraints on $f(x)$.

Comment: @AlexSilva, ah I see. I misunderstood what you had written, but now I see you have imposed an additional condition.