# Any example of strongly convex functions whose gradients are Lipschitz continuous in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ be strongly convex and its gradient is Lipschitz continuous, i.e., for some $l>0$ and $L>0$ we have $$f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{l}{2}||y-x||^2,$$ and $$||\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)||\leq L||y-x||$$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

For such a function, the only example I can come up with  is the quadratic function $$f(x)=x^T A x +B x + C$$ where $A$ is positive definite. I wonder if there is any other example? Thanks.

Note: the strong convexity and Lipschitz continuity hold for the whole $\mathbb{R}^N$; otherwise $e^x$ ($x\in\mathbb{R}$) is good enough in $[0,1]$.

-- New Remark: I ask this question because these two assumptions are often seen in optimization papers. Functions that satisfy one of the two are easy to think of; to satisfy these two assumptions at the same time, I really doubt how many functions exist.

-- Finally came up with an example by myself:
$$f(x)=\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})+x^2,x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Strong convexity: 
$$\nabla f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+2x,$$
$$\nabla^2 f(x) = -\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}+2.$$
Since $$\left|\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}\right|=\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right|\frac{1}{1+x^2}<1,$$
strong convexity follows from $$3 > \nabla^2 f(x)>1.$$

Lipschitz continuous gradient:
\begin{align}
\left|\nabla f(x+h)-\nabla f(x)\right|&\stackrel{(a)}{=}\left|\nabla f(x)+\nabla^2 f(y)h-\nabla f(x)\right|\\
&=\left|\nabla^2 f(y)h\right|\\
&\leq 3|h|
\end{align}
where $(a)$ is from the mean value theorem and $y$ is some number in $[x,x+h]$ for $h\geq 0$ or $[x+h,x]$ for $h<0$.

Comment: Yes, have corrected it.

Comment: Now it's clear. So this question reduces to find another convex function that has Lipschitz gradient on the whole $\mathbb{R}^N$ space. Hopefully I can find one :)

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the earlier confusion!

Comment: I think to avoid confusion for others I shall delete my incorrect comment. You may wish to delete/restate followups.

Comment: Ha ha! See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105703/hessian-related-convex-optimization-question). I was right before, but I didn't know it :-) You *can* make any function with a Lipschitz-continuous gradient---even if non-convex---strongly convex by adding a strongly convex function with a sufficiently large value of (lower-case) $l$. That's not what I *meant* to say, but it would seem it is still true.

Comment: Thank you. This seems possible when the Lipschitz continuous gradient constraint is added for the original function. At least I haven't got a counter-example. But I have new doubts on the question in your link where the function is only required to be twice differentiable. Say, again, $f(x)=-e^{x_1+x_2}$, then the hessian cannot be positive definite for any fixed $\lambda$ there.

Comment: That's a good point, but is that function Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: @MichaelGrant Just let you know I finally came up with an example.

Comment: Note that $\nabla f$ is $L$-Lipschitz iff $f(y)\le f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{L}{2}\lVert y-x\rVert^2$, thus if $f$ is $l$-strongly convex, $f$ is sandwiched between two quadratic functions as follows:
$$ f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{l}{2}||y-x||^2 \leq f(y)\le f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{L}{2}\lVert y-x\rVert^2 $$ hence
$$ \frac{l}{2}||y-x||^2 \leq  f(y) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) \leq \frac{L}{2}\lVert y-x\rVert^2  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example on $\mathbb R: f(x) = x^2-\cos x.$

A way to make lots of examples: Let $f$ be any positive bounded continuous function on $[0,\infty).$ For $x\ge 0,$ set

$$g(x) =\int_0^x \int_0^t f(s)\, ds\,dt.$$

Extend $g$ to an even function on all of $\mathbb R.$ Then $g$ satisfies the requirements.